# How to insert Binary tree to array

Tags: tree, binary-tree, pseudocode

I tried to write pseudo code to take a binary tree and insert it into an array according to **Level order** (aka **Breadth first**) traversal.

What I tried to write:

```
InsertToArray(Node *T):
    First, Create new Arr[size of the tree], Create S Queue
    Push(S,T)
    For i=0 to Len(Arr) do:
        IF 2*I smaller than Len(Array):
            Temp=Pop(S)
            Arr[i]=Temp
            Arr[2i]=Temp.Left
            Arr[2i+1]=Temp.Right
            IF T.Left isn’t NULL then Push(S,T.Left)
            IF T.Right isn’t NULL then Push(S,T.Right)
        Else IF 2*I larger than Len(Array): break the loop
```

I don't think it's correct code, I don't really know how to write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you do not mention the tree is a complete binary tree, the way you handle array index makes no sense here.

One easy way is to do a regular [level-order traversal](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/level-order-tree-traversal/) and append the current element to the array.

Comment: in my case i need to insert maximun heap to array with level-order traversal how can i write it?